# Stream awk during file generation/ upload from user to my server

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, pipe

I have a redhat server on which I very large files get uploaded by users. Once the files are completely uploaded, I run a script on them to parse the data. Its a bash script with 90% awk in there.

Is there a way for my to start awking the script as it is being downloaded? Sort of line a streaming awk for more realtime results?

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: what tool do you use for downloading? curl? wget?

Comment: Made an important edit. Its not a download. users upload these files to my server.

Comment: same question: by what process are they uploaded, and can you insert a pipe to awk in that process? what you're telling us is "I have this black box. how do I ..."

Comment: check this https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-info - if inotify exists for your redhat - you can watch for filesystem changes and run your awk immediately when the change is detected...

Comment: If you have access to the server code you could just feed the data to your script as you receive it. Is this what you need? In other words can you tell more us about the process responsible to receive the data?

Comment: i know `tail -f <filename>` keeps on appending to output. And also `tail -f <filename> | awk '{print $2}' is working. But somehow, i'm not able to capture this stdout to a file. Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tail -f` to read a file as it is being written. Example (GNU coreutils 8.21):

```bsh
tail -n +0 -f --pid $SOME_PID $SOME_FILE | $YOUR_SCRIPT
```

`-n +0` means that `tail` will start outputting from the beginning of the file. `-f` tells `tail` to output new data as the file grows. `--pid` terminates `tail` after the given process dies; `tail` has no other way to know when to stop watching the file for updates.

Answer (score 0):

how do you download? with wget you can do the following

```
wget -q -O- http://someurlthatdoesntexist.com | grep 'some word'
```

so, piping into a bash script should be as easy.

Comment: Actually its a an upload by some other user. The file is accessible to me but only part of it as the user uploads.